# dlopen/dlclose with couple of so, blocked on dlopen

Tags: linux, dlopen, shared-libraries

Two different so dlopen & dlclose couple of times, blocked on dlopen.

Hangs on `dlopen`, which outputs nothing, cpuidle down to 0%, and couldn't quit via *ctrl+c*.

```
LOG_TRACE("attaching...");
handle = dlopen(plugin_path.c_str(), RTLD_LAZY);
LOG_DEBUG("dlopen called");     // this line did not output, after success couple of times;
```

then I use gdb attach to the procedure:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000002a960dbe60 in tcmalloc::ThreadCache::InitTSD () at src/thread_cache.cc:321
#1  0x0000002a960d51bf in TCMallocGuard (this=Variable "this" is not available.) at src/tcmalloc.cc:908
#2  0x0000002a960d5e00 in global constructors keyed to _ZN61FLAG__namespace_do_not_use_directly_use_DECLARE_int64_instead43FLAGS_tcmalloc_large_alloc_report_thresholdE () at src/tcmalloc.cc:935
#3  0x0000002a960fafc6 in __do_global_ctors_aux () at ./src/base/spinlock.h:54
#4  0x0000002a96010f13 in _init () from ../plugins/libmonitor.so
#5  0x0000002a00000000 in ?? ()
#6  0x000000302ad0acaf in _dl_init_internal () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#7  0x000000302aff725c in dl_open_worker () from /lib64/tls/libc.so.6
#8  0x000000302ad0aa60 in _dl_catch_error () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#9  0x000000302aff79fa in _dl_open () from /lib64/tls/libc.so.6
#10 0x000000302b201054 in dlopen_doit () from /lib64/libdl.so.2
#11 0x000000302ad0aa60 in _dl_catch_error () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#12 0x000000302b201552 in _dlerror_run () from /lib64/libdl.so.2
#13 0x000000302b201092 in dlopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 () from /lib64/libdl.so.2
#14 0x000000000041b559 in uap::meta::MetaManageServiceHandler::plugin_action this=0xb26000, _return=@0x7fbffff500, plugin_name=@0x7fbffff4e0, plugin_path=@0x7fbffff570, t=Variable "t" is not available.)
at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.5/../../../../include/c++/3.4.5/bits/basic_string.h:1456
#15 0x000000000041b0bc in uap::meta::MetaManageServiceHandler::plugin_action (this=0xb26000, _return=@0x7fbffff500, plugin_name=@0x7fbffff4e0, plugin_path=@0x7fbffff570, t=uap::meta::PluginActionType::RELOAD)
at server/service_handler.cpp:173
#16 0x0000000000417641 in uap::meta::test_Service_Handler_suite_test_case_manage_service_plugin_action_Test::TestBody (this=0xb16080) at test_load.cpp:73
#17 0x00000000004446c6 in testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::Test, void> (object=0xb16080, method={__pfn = 0x21, __delta = 0}, location=0x537f30 "the test body")
at ../../../../com/btest/gtest/src/gtest.cc:2744
#18 0x000000000042dd1c in testing::Test::Run (this=0xb16080) at ../../../../com/btest/gtest/src/gtest.cc:2766
#19 0x000000000042e8b4 in testing::TestInfo::Run (this=0xb17160) at ../../../../com/btest/gtest/src/gtest.cc:2958
#20 0x000000000042f415 in testing::TestCase::Run (this=0xb23000, runtype=0) at ../../../../com/btest/gtest/src/gtest.cc:3160
#21 0x0000000000436352 in testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::RunAllTests (this=0xb22000) at ../../../../com/btest/gtest/src/gtest.cc:5938
#22 0x0000000000434299 in testing::UnitTest::Run (this=0x6f4220, run_type=0) at ../../../../com/btest/gtest/src/gtest.cc:5449
#23 0x0000000000434268 in testing::UnitTest::Run (this=0x6f4220) at ../../../../com/btest/gtest/src/gtest.cc:5387
#24 0x0000000000455404 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fbffff8c8) at ../../../../com/btest/gtest/src/gtest_main.cc:38
```

actually i have redefined the four functions:

```
void __attribute__((constructor)) dlinit()                                                                                                                                                                   
{
}

void __attribute__((destructor)) dldeinit()
{
}

void _init()
{
}

void _fini()
{
}
```

Comment: What program exhibit this behavior, with what plugin? How was both the program and the plugin built? What is your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable? Does your `plugin_path` contain a `/` ? What is its value? And you should add a `fflush(NULL);` after your code above!

Comment: thanks for the reply, I just did not set LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and plugin_path with absolute path start with /, does fflush necessary , since i just add printf here, but my code does not, it's not fflush issue, since hang at dlopen

Comment: I don't understand how and why you believe that the code is hanging at `dlopen` time? Did you use the debugger ? Show the code of the plugin, and more code of your program.

Comment: LOG_TRACE("attaching...");
handle = dlopen(plugin_path.c_str(), RTLD_LAZY);
LOG_DEBUG("dlopen called");     // this line did not output, after success couple of times;

Comment: Use `valgrind` to check that your heap is not badly corrupted.

Comment: looks hang on _init(), but i defined it null

Comment: Your backtrace mention some `malloc`; I suspect a heap corruption elsewhere. Please use `valgrind` !

Comment: any other way instead of this tool?

Comment: Why do you dislike `valgrind` ? You could also buy [purify](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/products/purifyplus/?S_TACT=105AGY59&S_CMP=09&ca=dtl-0903)!

Comment: i use "valgrind --leak-check=full xxx" nothing wrong output, and my program still hang there

Comment: Suggestion: first debug your heap issues (using `valgrind` or something else) without using any plugin.

Comment: failed to find useful info via valgrind:--11221-- Discarding syms at 0x8ddc6e0-0x8eb5588 in /xxx/plugins/libsample.so due to munmap()
--11221-- Reading syms from /xxx/plugins/libsample.so which correspond to dlclose and dlopen , then hang with previous gdb info

Comment: I think I have found the root cause: in gdb info , the hang comes form tcmalloc, i have read the tcmalloc corelated code , and couple of locks, then i complie and link so without tcmalloc, nothing happens, this would be tcmalloc bugs when work with so

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found the root cause: in gdb info , the hang comes form tcmalloc, i have read the tcmalloc corelated code , and couple of locks, then i complie and link so without tcmalloc, nothing happens, this would be tcmalloc bugs when work with so

Comment: Do you know what the hang was?  I am loading a library with dlopen which, for some reason, is opening a second library.  Inside this load tcmalloc is live locking.  I'll take a look through the source too, but if you already found the problem it'd be great to know.

Answer (score 0):

You should compile both your application and your plugin with `gcc -Wall -g` and use the debugger `gdb` (don't forget to compile the plugin sources also with `-fPIC` and to link its object files with `-shared`).

As you probably know, `dlopen`-ing a shared object will run the function having a `constructor` [function attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) (and also, as [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) says, the obsolete `_init` function). Also, constructors of C++ static data have the `constructor` attribute.

I guess that some of these constructors is blocked somehow (perhaps on input). You could also `strace` your program.

<sup>There might be some other reasons for such blocking, e.g. `dlopen`-ing an NFS mounted file from an unresponsive NFS server, etc...</sup>

See also [rtld-audit(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/rtld-audit.7.html), [ld.so(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) and `LD_DEBUG` environment variable (try to set it to `all`). Also, run `ldd` on both the plugin and the program.

BTW, in your code the lack of terminating newline `\n` in your `printf` format strings is suspicious (and bad taste), and you should print `dlerror()` when `dlopen` fails. At least add a call to `fflush(NULL);` after your code. Try to code instead:

```
handle = dlopen(plugin_path.c_str(), RTLD_LAZY);
if(!handle) { 
    printf("dlopening %s failed %s\n", plugin_path.c_str(), dlerror());
} else { 
    printf("dlopen %s success\n", plugin_path.c_str());
}
fflush(NULL);
```

You may also have corrupted your heap (elsewhere in your program) to the point that `dlopen` (or your plugin) cannot work anymore. Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to hunt memory corruption bugs!

Comment: yes, those compile and link para already added. and there is not _init _fini or andy constructor function. actually , plugins dlopen and dlclose correct sometimes, and hang sometimes ;